# How to populate POJO class from custom Hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate, and trying to use it in a Spring MVC application.  I have a custom query like the following:

```
public List<MyResults> findEmployees() {
   String queryString = "select E.firstname, E.lastname, A.city, A.state
      from Employee E, Address A, where ...."; // whatever where clause
   SQLQuery query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
   query.setString(...) // set query parameters
   return query.list();
}
```

This doesn't work.  The query runs, but it returns a list of objects.
How do I tell Hibernate to use my `MyResults` class?

```
class MyResults {
    private String firstName;
    // other fields in the search

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this firstName = firstName;
    }

    // other getters & setters
}
```

I'm also not sure what annotations `MyResults` needs?

I've tried a couple things:

```
return (List<MyResults>)query.list();
```

though this cast doesn't do it.

I've tried using a ResultTransformer:

```
 query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(MyResults.class));  //done before the return
```

but that causes an

> ClassClastException: MyResults cannot be cast to java.util.Map.

Can someone show me how to set this kind of query up correctly in Hibernate?

Comment: Please, add the full `MyResults` class. It is unclear: `MyResults` is `DTO` or  an entity. Does it has a plain structure or it has the nested objects.

Comment: It's a DTO -- not an Entity.  Just a plain structure.  A few field variables with getters and setters.  That's all.

Comment: So you don't need this `@Column(name = "FirstName")`

Answer (score 0):

The cause of `ClassClastException: MyResults cannot be cast to java.util.Map` is that Hibernate converts aliases for column names to upper case — `firstName` becomes `FIRSTNAME`. And it is really need the setter `setFIRSTNAME()` in the `DTO`. Don't know, it is a bug or feature.

To solve this issue, please, see my answer to your other question:

[mapping Hibernate query results to custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423885/3405171)

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is using the `NamedNativeQuery` as suggested, but making `MyResults` an `Entity`.  Like so:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findMyResult",  query = "select E.firstname, E.lastname, A.city, A.state from Employee E, Address A, where ....", resultClass = MyResults.class)
class MyResults {
    private String firstName;
    // other fields in the search

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this firstName = firstName;
    }
    // other getters & setters
}
```

Note however the `Entity` class is **not** annotated with `@Table`.

And then in my DAO class:

```
public List<MyResults> checkResults() {
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("findMyResult");
    query.setParameter("employeeID", "1234");
    return (List<MyResults>)query.list();
}
```

My question now is:  why does this work?

Comment: `@Table` doesn't need, if you have an `@Entity` annotation. I use `@Table` to specify a table name. It works, because of `@NamedNativeQuery` is a JPA way, a transformer is not used for that.

Comment: @Chris: See [`NamedNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html): *The NamedNativeQuery annotation can be applied to an entity or mapped superclass.* so if you use `@Entity`  it is working. But I think, this solution smells.

Comment: @dur I have to agree the solution smells :)  I don't like it myself.  One of my coworkers just played around with things and got this to work.  I guess my problem with all this is that I don't know enough of the basics of Hibernate to really know what's what.  Feel like I'm throwing code at it without understanding the fundamentals.

Answer (score -1):

You can use named query instead.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "findMyResult",  query = "select E.firstname, E.lastname, A.city, A.state from Employee E, Address A, where ....",resultClass = MyResults.class
)
class MyResults {
    private String firstName;
    // other fields in the search

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this firstName = firstName;
    }
    // other getters & setters
}
```

Named queries are global access and can call using getNameQuery

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findMyResult")
.setString("employee_id", "7277");
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but now it doesn't find the named query :(

In my DAO, I have:
    Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("findMyResult")
    query.setParameter("employee_id", "7277");

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't finished:

I tried this solution, but now it doesn't find the named query :(

In my DAO:

List<MyResults> checkResults(String employeeID) {
    Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("findMyResult")
    query.setParameter("employee_id", employeeID);
    List<MyResults> list = query.list();
    return list;
}

but it's not finding "findMyResults", though the class should be being scanned in my config, since it's placed in with my other Entity classes that SessionFactory is scanning. Can a non-Entity class have a Named Query?

Comment: @Chris: See [NamedNativeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html): *The NamedNativeQuery annotation can be applied to an entity or mapped superclass.*, so the answer is no.